# "Templates in other repositories may not specify a repository source when referencing another template" when trying advanced pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-server-2020

I am trying to find a solution for a rather complicated Azure Devops build pipeline.

I have 3 repositories (lets call them RepoA, RepoB and RepoC) which each contain templates for jobs that need to run for builds within those repositories.

I also have a Build repository which contains templates for tasks that are used by the jobs in all 3 of the main repositories.

I have run into a major problem when trying to build a unified pipeline that can run jobs across the different repositories however.  While I can implement a pipeline with a repository resource pointing to RepoA, RepoB and RepoC, when I add a template job from any of those repos using the templateJob.yaml@RepoA syntax, I receive an error due to the commonTaskTemplate.yaml@build reference within the job template in RepoA.

> Templates in other repositories may not specify a repository source
> when referencing another template.

Is there any clean work around for this issue?  I could implement the task templates as custom tasks in an Azure Devops Extension, but that will make it much harder to make any changes to those shared tasks.  I could also re-implement the shared tasks in every branch of every repo, but that makes a maintenance nightmare as the tasks would be near impossible to update.

It seems like every alternative I can come up with results in it being quite difficult to update the common tasks and it seems like there should be some way to do this more easily since I can't imagine that needing common tasks across repositories and a common pipeline that builds across repositories can be that uncommon of a thing.

Any other ideas on how to work around this limitation?

Comment: Related question running into the same technical issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68709301/2157640

Comment: Do you need to run the tasks for the three repositories in a single pipeline? If they can be built separately, there might be three separate pipelines that perform the build and a single pipeline (triggered by any of the three, if you want so) that performs the deployment, links them or whatever is needed.... The downside is that it is not possible to trigger the build of everything in just one step -- three separate pipelines need to be run.

Comment: @Palec that's basically what we are running now with each of them as their own pipeline.  The goal here is to make sure they all run as a unit to simplify things for our developers.

Comment: Also, just for informational sake, the way we worked around it was that I implemented the shared steps in an Azure Devops extension using powershell tasks.  It works well enough.  It isn't ideal as updates are a pain, but fortunately we don't have any shared code that needs to be updated regularly.

Comment: When the pipelines are triggered by a change in master, it is better when the pipelines are separate as only the code from a single repository is rebuilt, which takes less time than building three repos. Even manually, it often makes sense to rebuild just a single component; the pipeline should not force rebuild of everything. But I still do understand the need to force a fresh build of multiple repos (multiple pipelines) at once, e.g. when the deployment is not continuous and the build that goes to the release is being prepared.

Comment: I have two solutions in my mind, which I have yet to test in our team. The first one is making a pipeline that does no work at all and serves just as a trigger for other pipelines (the separate pipelines for components). The second one is to use a script that uses the DevOps API to run the pipelines.

Comment: But maybe there is a good reason why building the components separately is not feasible. I just fail to imagine what reason that might be. When the components are in separate repos, they should be fairly independent.

Comment: @Palec yeah, one is a framework on which the other depends.  Them being in separate repos is mostly a thing due to the scale of both.  These are very large, very old projects.  They also don't always run back to back, but this particular case is a build designed to do validate the a change that impacts the framework doesn't cause issues the entire way up the stack.