# Using templates that themselves use templates located in other repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to use several job/steps templates from multiple repositories. I have the following dependencies in my YAML pipeline:

pipeline.yaml@RepoA -> template1.yaml@RepoB -> template2.yaml@RepoC

It looks like Azure DevOps only supports referencing templates only one level deep.

This is the sample code I am using:

```
# pipeline.yaml@RepoA

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: RepoB
      type: Git
      name: RepoB

extends:
  template: Build/YAML/Jobs/test-sdk.yaml@RepoB
```

```
# Build/YAML/Jobs/test-sdk.yaml@RepoB

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: RepoC
      type: Git
      name: RepoC

jobs:
- job: AnotherJob

  steps:
  - template: Common/Steps/Initialize/ShowPackageVariables_01.yaml@RepoC
```

The above code sample throws an error while parsing the template:

> /Build/YAML/Jobs/test-sdk.yaml@RepoB (Line: 23, Col: 15): Templates in other repositories may not specify a repository source when referencing another template. The template reference 'Common/Steps/Initialize/ShowPackageVariables_01.yaml@RepoC' is not allowed.

Any ideas how to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: We set up a separate repo BuildTemplates where all templates used in multiple repos are stored. Up tonow I didn't try to use templates there which references other templates but  that should be easier. (Which repos are named as sources in the build tab of your pipeline? All referenced repos need to be mentioned there - and propably there is the transitive reference missing.)

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation of repository resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource) nor [usage of other repositories with templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) does not mention that this is possible. The error message is very explicit about repo references being forbidden in templates that are themselves in a different repo than the pipeline -- the only exception is the `@self` reference explicitly designed for this purpose.

There is no way around that limitation for now. YAML pipelines are completely parsed before they start executing, template references are resolved when parsing the pipeline and the parser states it does not support the case you've described.

This holds for both Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server 2020.

VS Developer Community has [a request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/templates-in-other-repositories-may-not-specify-a/820065) (originally posted [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/309)) titled with the first sentence of the error message. It is marked completed, but from the comments, it looks like the supposed resolution is the "extends" feature, which is not the case.